# Big-O Induction

Tags: asymptotics, induction

In my Algorithms course, our first assignment is a set of induction problems. I learned (very poorly) how to do this in my discrete mathematics course two years ago, but it wasn't a very comprehensive course.

My first problem is to check equivalence of the following:

$$c^{(n+b)} = O(c^n)$$ where b and c are both constants, c > 1 and b $\geq$ 1.

My base case set c=2, n<sub>0</sub>=3, q=100 and b=4, producing:

$$2^{3+4} \leq 100 * 2^3$$

Which simplifies to:

$$128 \leq 800$$

Which is true, so I can do the k+1 step. This is where I get really confused, although my understanding is that all this is, is algebra. I do my substitutions and get here:

$$c^{(k+1)+b} \leq q*c^{k+1}$$

From this point, I think I remember having to make the left side of the k+1 equation look like the original left side (except k instead of n), so I think I can do this:

$$c^kc^1c^b \leq qc^kc^1$$

Assuming I can do that, then I can divide either side by $c^1$ and get this:

$$c^{k+b} \geq qc^k$$

But here's where I'm stuck. How do I prove/disprove this?

**Edit:**

This is actually the ending point. Because $q$, $c$, $b$, and consequently $c^b$ are constants, the statement reduces to:

$$c^k \geq c^k$$

Which is true.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to prove whether or not $c^{n+b}$ is equal to $O(c^n)$.

Comment: You shold check your notations again. Usually
$$f\in \mathcal{O}(g)\ \ (x\to x_0) :\Leftrightarrow \exists C, \epsilon > 0, \text{s.t. } f(x) \leq C g(x) \qquad \forall\ x: |x-x_0| < \epsilon$$
Or similar for $x_0 = \infty$.

Comment: $b$ and $c$ are constants, but do not try to give them particular values.

Comment: @GEdgar From our examples in class, I think we were supposed to give them values just so we could prove that a base case was true (I realize that we can make anything true by doing that, I don't know if that's intentional, or if I'm doing it wrong though).

Comment: @AlexR Sorry, but most of that went over my head.

Comment: Roughly you are trying to show that for large $n$ there is some $K$ such that $c^{n+b} \le K c^n$. If this was true, then you would have $c^b \le K$. What values of $K$ would work? (I don't see the induction part of all this.)

Comment: What Alex wrote as $f\in \mathcal{O}(g)$, and what almost everyone else writes as $f = \mathcal{O}(g)$, is (confusingly) not an equation.  And it is not something to be proved by induction.

Comment: @copper.hat We're supposed to form inductive proofs for these problems. As for your question.. Would no $K$ work, because $c^b$ grows exponentially and will always be larger than a constant?

Comment: @copper.hat Nevermind that. In an answer below it's explained to me a bit more clearly that $c^b$ is a constant. My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you required to use induction here?  This is not a particularly difficult problem, as Big-O problems go!

Remember that $f(n)=O(g(n))$ if there is a constant $C$ and $N>0$ such that $\lvert f(n)\rvert\leq C\cdot g(n)$ for all $n\geq N$.  (In other words: $f(n)$ is *eventually* bounded by a constant times $g(n)$.)

Now, note that $c^{n+b}=c^bc^n$... and $c^b$ is a constant!

Comment: Yeah, we're required to use induction. I think my major problem was that I didn't recognize $c^b$ as a constant. Just to recap what you're saying, because $c^b$ is a constant, we have $c^n$ = $O(C^n)$ .. which would be true, because it can be bounded by itself?

Comment: Exactly!  It is certainly true that $\lvert c^n\rvert\leq c^n$ for all $n\geq 1$ (say).

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense! If I wrote out the proof real quick, would you double check it for me, just for peace of mind?

Comment: Write it up as an answer to your question here!  I'll take a look at it, and others probably will too.

Comment: I actually couldn't answer my own question, since I just joined this stack exchange network today. It's in the OP as a result. Thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to give a comprehensive introduction into the notation at first.
When you wirte $f = O(g)$, you actually mean $f\in \mathcal{O}(g)$, where $f,g$ are functions on the same domain $f,g: D \to \mathbb{R}$.
Also $\mathcal{O}$ is used to express that something grows at most as much as something else (1.), or that something decreases at least as fast as something else (2.), so you need to define some sort of limit point at wich your $\mathcal{O}$ ("order") is interesting. Call this $x_0 \in D$ we have two cases for the actual definition of $\mathcal{O}$:

1. $x_0 < \infty$, usually $x_0 = 0$, for example for numerical algorithms' accuracy $\mathcal{O}(h^p)$ is common.
   $$f\in \mathcal{O}(g) :\Leftrightarrow f(x) \leq C g(x) \qquad \text{for all } x \text{ "close enough" to } x_0$$
2. $x_0 = \infty$, usually for computation time etc.
   $$f\in \mathcal{O}(g) :\Leftrightarrow f(x) \leq C g(x) \qquad \text{for "sufficiently large" } x$$

   ---

Your special case is very simple, and implicitly takes $x_0 = \infty$. What you show is
$$c^{n+b} = c^b \cdot c^n = C c^n \leq C c^n \qquad \forall\ n \in \mathbb{N}$$
(the $\leq$ is trivial here)
So we found a constant $C = c^b$ which gives us
$$c^{n+b} \leq C c^n \qquad \forall\ h\in\mathbb N$$
and this, by definition, means
$$c^{n+b} \in \mathcal{O}(c^n) \qquad (c^{n+b} = \mathcal{O}(c^n))$$
So the proof basically consists of realising that for $c,b$ constant, $c^b$ is also constant.

Comment: This is clearer now, but it's incredible overkill for the question at hand. I don't come from a mathematical background, rather a computer science one, so a lot of this isn't in our coursework. I appreciate you taking the time to elaborate though!

Comment: The problem with the quick-and-dirty solutions is that students tend not to truly grasp what they are actually doing there. So I try to explain to you, what the notation actually means and from this starting point, the task at hand is a particularly easy one.